# cURL - Failed to connect to example.com: Address already in use

Tags: php, curl

I run a Christmas-related website as a hobby. It's a PHP website which serves as a frontend for a backend REST web-service. The PHP website makes about 2-3 GET requests to the backend REST service for each pageload.

The requests are made via PHP's stock cURL extension.

Normally this works fine, but this Christmas, due to massively increased load, I observed the site was crashing with HTTP 500 errors, specifically the error is:

> cURL Error: '7' - 'Failed to connect to backend.webservice.com port 443: Address already in use'

Searching online for this just yields other pages describing obvious port reuse/overlap, but nothing relevant for my case.

I was able to initially workaround this issue by scaling-out (the website runs on Windows Azure Websites with automatic load-balancing), but I'm wondering if there's a better way, such as if there's some connection-limit I could change.

Comment: seems the problem is that the OS ran out of available ports for `bind to port 0` (which makes the OS bind the socket on a "random" available port within a pre-determined range, seems you exhausted that range) - in linux, you'd increase /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range  , idk how to do that in Windows though

Comment: are you running this on a Server-edition of Windows?

Comment: quick googleing suggests the windows equivalent is: `netsh int <ipv4|ipv6> set dynamic <tcp|udp> start=number num=range` , may i suggest `netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=30000 num=30000` , would allow up to 30000 connections between port 30000-60000 (close to Debian Linux's default) -- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929851

Comment: @hanshenrik It's an Azure Website, so I cannot run `netsh`

Comment: then contact the administrator (or customer support, so they in turn can contact the sysadmin?) and let them know of the problem